# Logistic regression does not work after update to v.0.17

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I had something similar to this:

```
linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2').fit(X_train, y_train)
```

where X_train

```
array([[  2500. ,   5000. ,   5000. , ...,   4697.2,      3. ,  10600. ],
       ..., 
       [  2500. ,   3500. ,   3500. , ...,   3072. ,      3. ,  12800. ]])
```

and y_train:

```
array([  4.865146,  12.309128,   1.469881, ...,   5.248941,  11.84231 ,
         2.178483])
```

This worked without any errors or warnings in `v.0.16.1`, but after the upgrade to `v.0.17.1` it fails with an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: my y_train array.
```

Reading the documentation for [v16](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) and [v17](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) I have not found anything different. The only suspicious thing is this:

> Logistic Regression (aka logit, MaxEnt) classifier.

which kind of suggest that this is not actually a regression model, but classification model, so the y_train should be categories (but the same explanation was in v16, so I am not sure whether this is the case).

Anyway, I would like to know why is this happening and how can I make it work.

---

A runnable, self-contained example demonstrating the problem

```
X_train_1 = np.array([[ 2500.,  5000.], [ 4500.,  4500.]])
y_train_1 = np.array([  4.865146,  12.309128])
linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2').fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable, self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @BrenBarn I already removed everything that was not needed. I reduced the whole problem to basically one line and also partially included the input on which it fails. Not sure how more runnable and self-contained can it be. Anyway here are 3 lines that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What do you expect your model to do?  A logistic regression predicts a binary output variable, so values like 4.865146 don't make sense as Y values.  It could be that earlier versions of scikit erroneously accepted such Y values and did something wrong with them, and that they fixed it because those values don't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `LinearRegression`; logistic regression is actually a classification model (despite the misleading name). Not sure what your code was doing in the previous version, maybe it was treating each of the float values as a label?

Comment: Yes, logistic regression is a classification model. The equivalent regression model is not linear regression, though. In classical linear regression the output is any number on the real line and thus it does not work well for predicting probabilities. What OP wants is a generalized linear model with a logit link function.

Comment: @cel i don't think the OP is predicting probabilites though, the y values range between 0 and 13

Comment: Linear regression does absolutely a different thing. As I mentioned in the question, I also think that the problem is that their logistic regression is actually a classifier. I know that there is a logisticRegression which is an actual [regression model](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/141386/50804) and I am looking how to use it.

Comment: what is it you're trying to do? you can't fit a logit function to your data, since the logit outputs values between 0 and 1. i guess you could scale your data and use a generalised liner model like @cel suggested.

Comment: the comments in the post that you linked to is just saying that the output of a logistic regression is a probability between zero and 1, the training data is still expected to be categorical

Comment: oh no, the link was intended to show the difference between regression and classification. Anyway, thanks for help.